# QEMU execution traces for a simple program (guest mode)

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, riscv, kvm

I am starting my QEMU VM with the following command to get the execution traces for a simple hello world program in C.

`qemu-system-riscv64 -singlestep -d nochain,cpu -D $trace ${binary}`.

For guidance, I am following this [tutorial](https://static.linaro.org/connect/yvr18/presentations/yvr18-118.pdf). How is it that in slide 4, the size of the traces are 65K, whereas, my file just keeps growing (in GBs). I understand that it is monitoring the traces and hence the file size grows. My questions are:

1. Am I using the right command to get the execution traces? If not, please help in getting the correct command to only get the traces for the binary.
2. I am assuming that by giving the binary file as an argument, QEMU executes it when it launches the window. If this is not the case, how would I execute this hello world program inside the qemu window?
3. Lastly, I am assuming that the command is not doing full system virtualisation. I just need the traces, so I don't think that will be necessary. Is my assumption wrong? or is this command not sufficient?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been stuck in this for a while now.

Comment: qemu-*system*-riscv64 emulates the whole system. For just one binary, use `qemu-riscv64`

Comment: it says qemu-riscv64 command not found. @PawełŁukasik

Comment: but did you install it? I have no issue running both `qemu-riscv64` and `qemu-system-riscv64` on Ubuntu 20.02

Comment: I did install qemu with homebrew (mac) and qemu-system-riscv64 works fine.